# Set custom size of presenting modal in Swift fails — occupies full screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How can I get a presenting modal to be of custom size? Tried lots of different solutions, many which seem obsolete

This is how I instantiate the modal view from the parent view controller:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true
let vc = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "modalViewController"))!
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But, the modal view covers the full screen instead of just occupying 100 * 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` methods and `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` methods for customizing the presented `UIViewController` size.

To know how to implement custom animator,

Refer to: https://github.com/pgpt10/Custom-Animator

**Edit:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    //MARK: Private Properties
    fileprivate let animator = Animator()

    //MARK: View Lifecycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.transitioningDelegate = self
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    }

    //MARK: Button Action Methods
    @IBAction func dismissController(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

// MARK: - UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate Methods
extension ViewController : UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
{
    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
    {
        self.animator.transitionType = .zoom
        self.animator.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        return self.animator
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
    {
        return self.animator
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! These are methods on the parent view controller, right?

Comment: Could this also control the position of the modal?

Comment: Yes, you can customize it the way you want.

Comment: Tried the example and to do `self.animator.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)` before `self.animator.insets` but it was not respected? Any hints? :)

Comment: Did you follow all the steps on how to use it?

Comment: I believe so, I can get all stuff like `insets`, `duration`, `transitionType` working but not `size`.

Comment: Either give size or insets. Insets also calculates size. Try giving one of them.

Comment: Got it working, but it's erring now in the following way: if I set `size` and then dismiss the modal and open it again, the size is no longer respected (it becomes full screen). Any pointers?

Comment: Oh, it only applies to the `zoom`-transition

Comment: You can change the transition type too.

Comment: Yeah, but the if transition=`zoom` then if the modal is dismissed the size is reverted to full screen. Not the same problem with the other transitions.

Comment: Any idea on how to fix that bug?

Comment: thanks! however, that's exactly as I have done… here is a gif of the problem: https://media.giphy.com/media/3og0Iws6Gsq7bBXvnq/giphy.gif